# App runs normally but has "errors" during design time: "does not exist in namespace" and "an error occured when finding the resource dictionary"

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, namespaces, resourcedictionary

My application has certain errors, in its error box during design time, to do with it's resource dictionary. For example, in my Main Window a resource dictionary is called as follows;

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

I get a blueline on the middle line saying "An error has occurred while finding the resource dictionary "Resources.xaml". Yet, the Resources.xaml is in the root folder of the project, and so is the MainWindow.

I am aware that there are similar questions like this out there, however the answers;

> "Make sure Resources.xaml is set to build action: page"
>
> "Make sure you are correctly referencing Resources.xaml"

were not helpful to me.

I have an additional problem in that, within the resource dictionary, I have errors telling me;

```
the name ProductDatabaseViewModel does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:gate2software.ViewModels"
```

and similarly;

```
the name ProductDatabaseView does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:gate2software.Views"
```

in the following xaml;

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProductDatabaseViewModel}">
    <vw:ProductDatabaseView />
</DataTemplate>
```

In reality both of these are available exactly where they are stated to be.

Any suggestions for either of my two problems would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do u mean Works Perfectly ?

Comment: does it still say this if you completely quit Visual Studio and restart, then open the app again?

Comment: What platform are you targeting? x64 or x86?

Comment: @Muds When I run the application things display as expected, only during design time does the blue line have any effect, meaning the main window is not visible at design time only run time.

Comment: @TheodosiusVonRichthofen Yes, they are still there.

Comment: @TheBlindSpring I'm running on x86 currently however program should run fine in x64

Comment: Are you referencing a DLL?

Comment: @TheBlindSpring Nope, there's no DLL being referenced anywhere in the app. It's a very strange error

Comment: If you go into your project properties and select the build menu, what is selected for the "Platform Target" option?

Comment: Change your **Platform Target** to any CPU. I have had this issue before, but I have no idea why this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your path is correct? or try like dis path:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source=ms-appx:///CustomControls/Resources.xaml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to close the designer process (sometimes this works)? 
Task Manager > Details > **XDesProc.exe** > end process. You will be able to reload it by clicking refresh in any VS view, but first rebuild all.

And by the way, Resources.xaml is for sure a ResourceDictionary type and not Page ? This kind of errors are shown also when you try to add a page as resource, not a ResourceDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue. My projects were targeted for a x64 build. I changed them to `Any CPU` See below and was able to see my view model data at design time.

[image: if(Platform Target == x64) throw new NoDesignTimeViewModelSupportException();]